# How to use Skyrim "Power" with new voice command Kinect?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, kinect

I have downloaded the new Kinect voice commands and now can't figure out how to use my "Natural Power" for my Kajit character. Before I could use Nighteye on the Rt bumper in place of Shouts, but now I can't seem activate the Nighteye Power.

Comment: Have you tried saying "dark eye see" in the cat tongue?

Comment: I had to disable Kinect voice commands in order to use an equipped power. It's really annoying ....

Answer (score 1):

Hold LB and then press RB to use equipped powers.